# How to make PdfLayer.SetPrint work with PdfStamper?

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm adding watermarks on existing PDF using the iText `PdfStamper` class. And I want these watermarks to be switched to on or off, so I'm using the class `PdfLayer`.
But I also want these watermarks to be always visible when the file is printed : I'm using the function `PdfLayer.setPrint()` then.
This is this last step that unfortunately doesn't work as expected.

Here's my code :

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:/Temp/input.pdf");
PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("C:/Temp/output.pdf"));
PdfWriter writer = stamp.getWriter();
PdfLayer layer = new PdfLayer("Watermarks", writer);
layer.setOn(true);
layer.setPrint("Watermarks", true);
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont();
PdfContentByte cb = stamp.getOverContent(1);
cb.beginText();
cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 18);
cb.beginLayer(layer);
cb.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "Watermark line 1", 50, 55, 0);
cb.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "Watermark line 2", 50, 40, 0);
cb.endLayer();
cb.endText();
stamp.close();
reader.close();
```

When I check the layer properties from Adobe Reader (version 10), I see that the "Initial State : Print" property stays at "Prints When Visible" while it should be "Always Print".

I also tried creating layers on a new PDF document and there the `setPrint()` works.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem. As a workaround, you can use `new Document` and `getImportedPage` instead of `pdfStamper`.
Unfortunately, you loose the hyperlink because all pages are converted to images. I tried to use `PdfCopy` but I reproduced the same issue. I am really interested in a solution allowing me to add a watermark without changing the source file.
Degraded sample solution :

```
        PdfReader pdfReaderS = new PdfReader(filepathS);
    Document document = new Document(pdfReaderS.getPageSizeWithRotation(1));
    PdfWriter pdfWriterD = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filepathD));
    document.open();
    PdfContentByte pdfContentByteD = pdfWriterD.getDirectContent();

    BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

    int n = pdfReaderS.getNumberOfPages();

    PdfLayer pdfLayer = new PdfLayer("Watermark", pdfWriterD);
    pdfLayer.setPrint("Print", true);
    pdfLayer.setView(visibleScreen); 

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {                  
        Rectangle pageSizeS =pdfReaderS.getPageSizeWithRotation(i);
        float pageWidth = pageSizeS.getWidth() / 2;
        float pageheight = pageSizeS.getHeight() / 2;
        float degree = (float)(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(pageSizeS.getHeight()/pageSizeS.getWidth())));

        document.setPageSize(pageSizeS);
        document.newPage();
        PdfImportedPage pdfImportedPage = pdfWriterD.getImportedPage(pdfReaderS, i);
        int rotation = pdfReaderS.getPageRotation(i); //This value can be 0, 90, 180 or 270. 

        if (rotation == 0) 
            pdfContentByteD.addTemplate(page, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        else if (rotation == 90)
             pdfContentByteD.addTemplate(page, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, pageSizeS.getHeight());
        else if (rotation == 180)
            pdfContentByteD.addTemplate(page, -1, 0, 0, -1, pageSizeS.getHeight(), pageSizeS.getWidth());
        else if (rotation == 270)
             pdfContentByteD.addTemplate(page, 0, 1, -1, 0, pageSizeS.getWidth(), 0);           

        pdfContentByteD.beginLayer(pdfLayer);
        pdfContentByteD.beginText();
        pdfContentByteD.setFontAndSize(baseFont, policeSize);
        pdfContentByteD.setColorFill(col);
        pdfContentByteD.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, text, pageWidth, pageheight, degree);
        pdfContentByteD.endText();
        pdfContentByteD.endLayer();
    }
    document.close();
    pdfReaderS.close();
```

Comment: This solution is enough for me, thanks. Anyway, I had to adapt a bit your code for the rotation : `if (r == 0) content.addTemplate(page, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); else if (r == 90)  content.addTemplate(page, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, pageSizeS.getHeight()); else if (r == 180) content.addTemplate(page, -1, 0, 0, -1, pageSizeS.getHeight(), pageSizeS.getWidth()); else if (r == 270) content.addTemplate(page, 0, 1, -1, 0, pageSizeS.getWidth(), 0);`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. My code want to add a image as watermark on every page of original pdf. And the watermark can only be viewed, not allow to print. I use `PdfStamper` and `PdfLayer.setPrint()` too. But it did not work. I read the itext java source and found a way to make it work. Here is code :

```
PdfWriter writer = stamp.getWriter();
PdfLayer layer = new PdfLayer("Watermarks", writer);
layer.setOn(true);
layer.setOnPanel(false);
layer.setPrint("watermark", false);
writer.addToBody(layer.getPdfObject(), layer.getRef());
```

It call `addToBody` after `setPrint`. This works well.

Comment: I use iText 5. I don't know if it is a bug. I read iText 7 java source, I think it is no problem for setPrint working in itext 7.